# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have upgrade poi version 3.16 to 4.12 in my application. After version upgrade, I got the error in runtime. I have xmlbeans 3.1.0 jar in my classpath and pom. ( still xmlbeans jar is a dependecy of poi-ooxml )

**Part Of My pom:**

```
 </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Exception :**

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.thy.util.CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CustomCharacterEncodingFilter.java:20)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:40012)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.commit(XSSFWorkbook.java:1774)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:490)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:236)
    at com.thy.yk.bean.ExcelSablonOlusturma.createExcelSablon(ExcelSablonOlusturma.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 38 more
```

I have tried to differeent version of Xmlbeans.jar but still got error.

Comment: There must be another `xmlbeans` jar of version lower than `3.1.0` somewhere in classpath.

Comment: I have checked again, there is no other version of xmlbeans in classpath.

Comment: There must be one. Try using the code of [first FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) to ask your class loader where `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions` came from.

Comment: Thanks! Classloader find jar in 
**file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans.jar**  Now how can solve this problem?

Comment: First question would be why `com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans.jar` exports `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions`, because that's weird. But if it is so, you need excluding `com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans` from your classpath when running code which needs using `org.apache.xmlbeans`. How to do depends on your environment. I am not a maven expert. But this could be a question to the maven experts here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved with weblogic.xml.
Classloader find jar in file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans.jar so weblogic exclude xmlbeans and project used new version.

```
  <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    
        <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                <wls:package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        </wls:container-descriptor>
    </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: The edit queue for this question is full, so I'll add here that the issue was identified by using the code of [first FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) to ask the class loader where org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions came from

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution online and it worked for me

1. exclude the xmlbeans dependency from apache poi

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

2. add separate dependency for xmlbeans

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

here is the link https://blog.csdn.net/HDXxiazai/article/details/105382356

Comment: works just great, dunno why

Comment: Which file is this put in?

Comment: the change is made in pom.xml