# I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while i am trying to use excel data?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, apache-poi

```
File src=new File("C:............xlsx");
      FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
      XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
      int rowCount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
```

This same code i was successfully  able to run in old jdk version, but in latest jdk version its throwing this error.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:110)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.<init>(XSSFCell.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.<init>(XSSFRow.java:77)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initRows(XSSFSheet.java:268)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:231)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:218)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:454)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:419)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:288)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:309)
```

Comment: Hi Roshni, can you please add the stack trace for more details? current JDK version and POI version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more details..

However, downgrading from POI 5.0.0 to perhaps POI 4.1.0 may save you days of agony.
I had tried so many recommendations that didn't work but downgrading resolved it for me.

Also, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62793697/4319941