# Probably got a version mismatch on `xmlbeans` in pom.xml when accessing Excel File

Tags: java, excel, maven-3, pom.xml

I got this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace(boolean)'
```

when using the following xmlbeans Version in `pom.xml`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have excluded the `xmlbeans` from the dependency of `poi`, `poi-ooxml` and `poi-ooxml-schema`.

How to get rid of the error message?

I expect to load Excel file via `fileInputStream` as follows:

```
        workbook= WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);
```

Comment: let apache poi bring the version it needs. don't load another one

Comment: I have it from the second answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789174/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-xmlbeans-xmloptions-setentityexpansionli

Comment: Unless you use exactly the same version as them, don't expect it to work